# segmentation fault (core dumped) Error while calling the mknode function

Tags: c, yacc

## define YYSTYPE struct node1 *

%token INT FLOAT CHAR DOUBLE VOID

start: Declaration Function Declaration1  {$$ = mknode($1, $2, $3,NULL,0);}

```
|Declaration Function             {$$=mknode($1,$2,NULL,NULL,0);}   
        
| Declaration                 {$$ =mknode($1,NULL,NULL,NULL,0); }

| Function                {$$ =mknode($1,NULL,NULL,NULL,0); }
;

Declaration1 :Function           {$$ =mknode($1,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL); }
;


Function: 

Type ID '(' ArgListOpt ')' CompoundStmt         {$$ = mknode($1,$2,$4,$6,NULL); }
;
```

Type: INT               {$$ = mknode(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"INT"); }

| FLOAT                 {$$ = mknode(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"FLOAT"); }

| CHAR                  {$$ = mknode(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"CHAR"); }

| DOUBLE                {$$ = mknode(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"DOUBLE"); }

| VOID                  {$$ = mknode(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,"VOID"); }

;

```
CompoundStmt: '{' StmtList '}'      {$$ =$2; }
;

StmtList: StmtList Stmt            {$$ = mknode($1,$2,NULL,NULL,NULL); }

|                   {$$=mknode(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);}
;

when i am running this on the input 

int mian()
{}


it is giving segementation fault at

char* newnode =(char*)malloc(strlen(token));



node1 *mknode(node1 *left1, node1 *left2, node1* left3,node1* left4,char *token)
{

  /* malloc the node */

  node1 *newnode = (node1 *)malloc(sizeof(node1));



  char *newstr = (char *)malloc(strlen(token));

  strcpy(newstr, token);



  newnode->left1 = left1;

  newnode->left2 = left2;

newnode->left3 = left3;

  newnode->left4 = left4;

  newnode->token = newstr;

  return(newnode);
}
```

what is the error here? plz help

Comment: i have replaced o with NULL still not working

Comment: @swati... What you are getting in token??? Please edit token value.

Comment: @Krishna i have added the above rules for the token

Comment: after the removal of segmentation fault now it is showing parsing failed while iam trying to run the program..but before this there was no parsing error..i have parsed the complete program before writing the actions and it was successfully parsing..but now its not..what could be the error

Comment: ~$ yacc c.y~$ lex c.l
~$ gcc y.tab.c -ll -ly
~$ ./a.out
int main()
{}
3 : syntax error 

Parsing failed

Answer (score 0):

While you should really run your program in a debugger to find it out, these two lines are a likely culprit:

```
char *newstr = (char *)malloc(strlen(token));

strcpy(newstr, token);
```

If `token` is `NULL` then both `strlen` and `strcpy` will most likely crash.

Dereferencing a `NULL` pointer is *undefined behavior* and will in most situations cause a crash. Before dereferencing a pointer, or calling a function that does, you need to check if the pointer is `NULL` or not.

Comment: i am passing NULL in place of token because i don't have a token value for that rule..what else should i pass in place of NULL

Comment: @swati Passing `NULL` to your function is okay, you just have to check for it before you use the string.

Comment: thanks @joachim segmentation fault is removed for this now...i checked token value before creating newstr

Comment: Btw. if `token` is not NULL, there is still `strlen()+1` to be allocated

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt yes i have written strlen()+1 this also..but still parsing is failed....this is not even parsing int main(){}